# Is there a way to return an optional value to the calling method from the ifPresent method?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I try to make a code more compact by coding a helper method, because the code is very repetitive.

The code consists of:

1. call a command (remote ssh, or local command, this part is not interesting for my question)
2. check if it was a success
3. if not, stop here and return the return code to the calling method (i.e. `return cr;`)
4. if success, continue with another command

I tried to create a helper method that do all that. If the command execution is a failure, it will return an `Optional<Integer>` of the return code. If it works as expected, it returns a `Optional.empty()`.

My question is how to do something like that:

```
public void topMethod()
{
    int cr = execCmds();
    ... do stuff with cr ...
}

private int execCmds()
{
    executeCmd("my command").ifPresent(cr -> return cr);
    executeCmd("my next command").ifPresent(cr -> return cr);
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I want to stop the flow if the return code is meaningful. If not it must continue. Is there a way to do that? (Something concise.)

For information, the `return cr` is invalid in the `ifPresent` lambda method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use [`Optional.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier))

`Optional.or()` was introduced with JDK 9, and expects a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) of `Optional`.

In a nutshell, method `or()` checks whether the `Optional` on which it is applied is empty, and if that's the case it replaces it with another optional. otherwise, if value is present, it would return the same optional (i.e. `Supplier` passed as an argument wouldn't be executed, functions are evaluated *lazily*).

```
public void topMethod() {
    int cr = execCmds();
    // do something with cr 
}

private int execCmds() {
    return executeCmd("my command")
        .or(() -> executeCmd("my next command"))
        .or(...) // more alternatives
        .orElse(0);
}

public Optional<Integer> executeCmd(String command) {
    return // something;
}
```

## Stream of Suppliers

Another option would be to create a Stream of `Supplier` of `Optional`.

It can be useful if you're using **JDK 8** (*and therefor can't use* `or`), or if `executeCmd()` returns an [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html#method-summary) which lacks method `or()`.

Stream would process each `Supplier` lazily, one at a time, and As well as in the previous solution each `executeCmd()` invocation would occur only if needed (*if the previous command failed to provide the result*).

Here's how it can be implemented:

```
public void topMethod() {
    int cr = execCmds();
    // do something with cr
}

private int execCmds() {
    return Stream.<Supplier<OptionalInt>>of(
            () -> executeCmd("my command"),
            () -> executeCmd("my next command")
            // ...
        )                                // Stream<Supplier<OptionalInt>>>
        .map(Supplier::get)              // Stream<<OptionalInt>>
        .filter(OptionalInt::isPresent)  // Stream<<OptionalInt>>
        .mapToInt(OptionalInt::getAsInt) // IntStream
        .findFirst()                     // OptionalInt
        .orElse(0);
}

public OptionalInt executeCmd(String command) {
    return // something;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the second part, even if I am using jdk 15, it's still a neat way to do it.

Comment: If the commands aren't too oversimplified for the question, the second example could be reduced to `Stream.of("commandOne", "commandTwo").flatMapToInt(c -> executeCmd(c).stream()).findFirst().orElse(0)`

Comment: @Holloway `Optional.stream()` was introduced with **JDK 9** (at the same time when `or()` appeared in the language). Therefore, it can't be applied with Java 8 (and with latter versions we can use `or()`), the only use-case would when `executeCmd()` returns `OptionalInt` and it can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Would chaining your commands with `or` work? Something like

```
private int execCmds()
{
    return executeCmd("command one")
             .or(() -> executeCmd("command two")
             .or(() -> executeCmd("command three")
             .orElse(0);
}
```